# Why does my border go over my form?

Tags: html, css

When i make my browser window smaller the border will not stay around the form, it will instead overlap? So will my sentence. How do I make the border stay around the the form and have the border height adjust for the length of the form with padding?

```css
#form_border{
    margin: auto;
    width: 400px; 
    
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
  
    
    
}
#form {
      
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 2em;
    text-align: center;
                    
}
#form form{display: block;}
#existing_account{ text-align: center;
                   text-decoration: none;
                   color: black;
}
    


input[type=submit] {
                    background:white;
                    border:1px solid;
                    border-color: #292929;
                    cursor:pointer;
                    border-radius: 5px; }   


input[type=submit] {
                    background:white;
                    border:1px solid;
                    border-color: #292929;
                    cursor:pointer;
                    border-radius: 5px; }
```

```html
<div id="form_border">
    <form id="form" method="post" action="">
        <p>Username:<br> <input type="text" name="user_name" /> <br></p>
        <p>Password:<br> <input type="password" name="user_pass"><br></p>
        <p>Password again:<br> <input type="password" name="user_pass_check"><br></p>
        <p>E-mail:<br> <input type="email" name="user_email"><br></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
     </form>
        <a id="existing_account" href="sign_in.php">Already have an account?</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why the wrapper element #form_border? Why would you not set the border on the form itself?

Comment: Because that’s what happens when you specify a height, and the content gets larger than that …?

Comment: i did not set the border around the form it self because i wanted something padding around the form and I ass told another div would be the best way to do this.

Comment: Well, you could try to put the `<a>` inside the form, remove the wrapper element, set the form to `width: 200px` and `padding: 2em 100px 0` and set the border on the form. Please let me know if this is anywhere near what you want.

Comment: @BillyNate that helps clean the code. Brining the <a> in to the foprm does help but it only means the border will cover it as well when the screen height changes.

Comment: @pralhad. your answer is great but it only means there is a minimum width. That  is helpful but does not fix the height issue. 
Im attachiing a screenshot. you can see how the border goes over the form. https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1J317NzMPlr6BETCMq1H8y8cEkL4y7FC4xPOma9vE20M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @BillyNate firefox and internet

Comment: Unfortunately in my Firefox the border doesn't do anything weird, making it hard to help you...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<style>
#form_border{
    margin: auto;
    width: 400px; 
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
}
#form {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}
#form form{
    display: block;
}
#existing_account{ 
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
input[type=submit] {
    background:white;
    border:1px solid;
    border-color: #292929;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-radius: 5px; 
}   
@media screen and (max-width:399px){
    input[type="text"],
    input[type="password"],
    input[type="email"]{
        width:90%;
    }
    #form_border{
        width:98%;
    }
    #form {
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="form_border">
    <form id="form" method="post" action="">
        <p>Username:<br> <input type="text" name="user_name" /> <br></p>
        <p>Password:<br> <input type="password" name="user_pass"><br></p>
        <p>Password again:<br> <input type="password" name="user_pass_check"><br></p>
        <p>E-mail:<br> <input type="email" name="user_email"><br></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
     </form>
        <a id="existing_account" href="sign_in.php">Already have an account?</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**You will observe:**

1. I have introduced the media query to manage the form size for the screens less than 400px in width.
2. Width of the form and form-elements has been taken care of in the media query.

**Scope for improvements:**

3. Restructure the HTML so it becomes more manageable.
4. use Media Queries more efficiently.
5. Use `width` values more efficiently.

**You use this [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/xbygy5ck/7/) demo link.**

Here are few more commonly used MEDIA QUERY BREAK POINTS which you may consider including in your CSS

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
/**********
iPad 3
**********/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 5 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6+ ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S3 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S5 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: your answer is great but it only means there is a minimum width. That is helpful but does not fix the height issue. Im attachiing a screenshot. you can see how the border goes over the form. docs.google.com/drawings/d/…

Comment: You can always take a hint from my answer and the way I have included the media-query. It will surely be easy for you to manage the height parameter. :)

Comment: You are always free to include as many media queries as you want. :) Please check my answer one more time. I have included few more **break points** which could be helpful for you.